# Attempting to access Tomcat datasource through ResourceLink is returning ResourceRefLink instead

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I'm attempting to access a datasource through a ResourceLink.

In the server.xml I have

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/nameXGlobal" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="usernameX" password="passwordX"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:urlinfo"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

In the context.xml I have the following:

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/nameX" global="jdbc/nameXGlobal" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

However when I attempt to perform a lookup I get the error "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.naming.ResourceLinkRef cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource", meaning it's not getting the datasource but simply the ResourceRefLink.
If I simply place the resource in the context directly instead of making it global through the server.xml I do not receive the error, so it seems the issue is with how I am referencing the resource in the context.xml.

I do not see a difference from how I am creating the ResourceLink in the context from Tomcat's own recommendation on this page: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html. What could I be missing that's causing the ResourceLink to fail to actually link to the resource?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? So far the only option seems to be, as @SirDieter 's answer suggests, putting the Resource in context.xml directly. Doesn't seem like a proper solution though.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works just putting the Resource Tag directly in the context.xml without ResourceLink